# Chrome 10 required field issue (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, forms, html, google-chrome, validation

It seems with the launch of Chrome 10 stable yesterday, required form fields (required="required") are now being handled by Chrome. This is great, BUT now it is ignoring my custom validation script (jQuery). Anyone know of a way to force Chrome to ignore it's built in validator, and use mine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert a `novalidate` attribute inside the `<form>` tag. This will turn off the browser validation.

Syntax: 
`<form method="post" action="/submit.php" novalidate>
   <input type="text" name="first_name" required />
   <button type="submit">Submit</submit>
</form>`

Comment: This works great. Exactly the type of simple solution I was looking for. Thanks Devin!

Answer (score 1):

You can preserve the required attribute and manage to replace it with CSS class in jQuery :

```
var $requiredFields = $('form').find('input[required="required"]');
$requiredFields.removeAttr('required').addClass('required');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class name for required fields, instead of `required="required"`

Comment: Yeah, that is always an option. Since this is going to effect multiple scripts across various websites, I was hoping for something a little cleaner / less time consuming.

Comment: You can always use jQuery to remove the attribute and insert the class name.